# Subtract values in different rows in SPSS

Tags: spss

I am completely new in SPSS and now trying to write syntax to manipulate my dataset.

I now have a dataset which looks like this:

V1  V2

1   2007/01/23

2   2007/02/25

.
.
.
.

First row "V1" is the row number and second row "V2" is the date.

I would like to find the difference between the dates "V2" for each 2 subsequent rows and create a new third column of data for the result.

However, I have no idea how to do the subtraction for data in two different rows.

Comment: are the values of v1 sequential, i.e. can you subtract odd rows from even ones ?

Answer (score 3):

Look up the lag function.  It gives you access to previous rows.  If you need to calculate against forward values look at the SHIFT VALUES command.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are interested in the number of days that lie between two dates.
The "ctime.days" function converts the value of the subtraction into the number of days.

```
COMPUTE ddiff = ctime.days(v2 - LAG(v2)).
EXECUTE.
```

Another solution would be using the "datediff" function:
The general syntax of this function is:

```
datediff(date1,date2,unit)
```

In your case you would use the following syntax:

```
COMPUTE ddiff = datediff(v2,LAG(v2),"days").
EXECUTE.
```

The second solution is a bit more flexible, as you can choose other output units such as "years", "quarters", "months", "weeks" and so on.